# Decorate functions in a CoffeeScript class

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, decorator

I'm writing a backbone application, and I would like to write an authenticated decorator that I can use to decorate a list of methods (routes) in the router class.

So I have a router with a few methods and have tried something like this. However, the decorator is not attached when I call the routes I want decorated.

```
class MyApp extends Backbone.Router

  routes: 
    ''         : 'home'
    'foo'      : 'foo'
    'bar'      : 'bar'


  authenticated: ['foo', 'bar'] 

  initialize: ->
    @decorateAuthenticatedFunctions()      

  decorateAuthenticatedFunctions: => 
    _.each @authenticated, (method)=>
      @[method] = (args)=>
        if @authorized()
          @[method].apply @, args
        else
        @navigate '', true

  authorized: =>
    @user? and @user.loggedIn 

  foo: =>
    #do stuff

  bar: =>
    #do stuff
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure `initialize` is being called at all? Add a alert of console.log in there to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few problems.

First, I don't think `initialize` is getting called for some reason.  I can tell because if it was getting invoked then it would be raising errors (see next point).  Now I'm no backbone expert, but maybe try using the constructor instead?

```
class MyApp extends Backbone.Router
  constructor: ->
    super
    @decorateAuthenticatedFunctions()
```

Second, that loop wont work.  You are replace `@[method]` with a new function, which calls on `@[method]` in that function.  When it succeeds, you get an recursively infinite function call.  So save a reference to the original function, and then call that reference withing the decorator function.

And while you are in there, no need for underscore since coffee script does loops very well.  And you don't even need a closure for this loop at all since you are using the loop value only immediately.

This slightly altered non backbone version works:

http://jsfiddle.net/ybuvH/2/

```
class MyApp

  authenticated: ['foo', 'bar'] 

  constructor: ->
    @decorateAuthenticatedFunctions()      

  decorateAuthenticatedFunctions: =>
    for method in @authenticated
      fn = @[method]
      @[method] = (args) =>
        if @authorized()
          fn.apply @, args
        else
          console.log 'denied'

  authorized: =>
    @user? and @user.loggedIn 

  foo: =>
    console.log 'foo'

  bar: =>
    console.log 'bar'

app = new MyApp

app.user = { loggedIn: no }
app.foo() # denied
app.bar() # denied

app.user = { loggedIn: yes }
app.foo() # foo
app.bar() # bar​
```

​

Comment: You don't want to provide your own `constructor`. The Backbone machinery will call `initialize`. He was missing some indentation on his `else` though, that could cause some unexpected behavior. There is an advantage to using `_.each`, that will use the native `forEach` if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having a `this` context issue.

Remember that the 'fat arrow' `=>` binds to the `this` at function definition time. So your `decorateAuthenticatedFunctions: =>` is binding to the global `this`, when you want to bind it to your `MyApp` instance instead.

Try this:

```
...

initialize: ->
  @decorateAuthenticatedFunctions.call(@) # Call with proper context

decorateAuthenticatedFunctions: ->    # Use skinny arrow
  _.each @authenticated, (method)=>
    @[method] = (args)=>
      if @authorized()
        @[method].apply @, args
      else
      @navigate '', true

authorized: ->                        # Use skinny arrow
  @user? and @user.loggedIn 

...
```

Comment: `=>` on method declarations works differently.  It instead insured `this` is always the instance. http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Foo%0A%20%20foo%3A%20%3D%3E

Comment: Hmmm... I think you're right. I still recommend analyzing the `this` context by debugging and `break`ing at the top of `decorateAuthenticatedFunctions`.